# "Procedure or function 'UPDATE' expects parameter '@Id', which was not supplied" in Windows Form

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

We created a Windows Form to update a table in SQL Server.

First I click Enter ID to retrieve details from database, then after changing some data, when I click on `Update` button, I get an error:

> Procedure or function 'UPDATE' expects parameter '@Id', which was not supplied.

Windows Form Design :

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXGm7.png)

Error :

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBIGg.png)

Code for Windows Form:

```
public partial class Update : Form
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=AMAR;Initial Catalog=Hotel;Integrated Security=True";

    public Update()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            TestObject t = null;
            string spName = "Get";
            //string queryText = "Select * from TestTable where Id = " +txtId.Text;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID.Text);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                t = new TestObject();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    t.Id = reader["ID"].ToString();
                    t.Status = reader["Status"].ToString();
                    t.FName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    t.LName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    t.Addr = reader["Address"].ToString();
                    t.City = reader["City"].ToString();
                    t.State = reader["State"].ToString();
                    t.Country = reader["Country"].ToString();
                    t.PhoneNo = reader["PhoneNo"].ToString();
                    t.Email = reader["EmailId"].ToString();
                    t.Pin = reader["Pincode"].ToString();
                    t.CheckIn = reader["CheckIn"].ToString();
                    t.CheckOut = reader["CheckOut"].ToString();
                    t.AdultNo = reader["AdultNo"].ToString();
                    t.ChildNo = reader["InfantNo"].ToString();
                    t.InfantNo = reader["InfantNo"].ToString();
                    t.RoomNo = reader["RoomNo"].ToString();
                };
            }

            Statustxt.Text = t.Status;
            txtfName.Text = t.FName;
            txtlName.Text = t.LName;
            txtAddr.Text = t.Addr;
            City.Text = t.City;
            State.Text = t.State;
            Country.Text = t.Country;
            PhoneNo.Text = t.PhoneNo;
            EmailID.Text = t.Email;
            Pincode.Text = t.Pin;
            CheckIN.Text = t.CheckIn;
            CheckOut.Text = t.CheckOut;
            Adult.Text = t.AdultNo;
            Child.Text = t.ChildNo;
            Infant.Text = t.InfantNo;
            RoomNo.Text = t.RoomNo;
        }
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Stat = Statustxt.Text;
        string FirstName = txtfName.Text;
        string LastName = txtlName.Text;
        string Address=txtAddr.Text;
        string Cities=City.Text;
        string States= State.Text;
        string  Countries =Country.Text;
        string  PhoneNos= PhoneNo.Text;;
        string  EmailId= EmailID.Text;
        string PinCode=Pincode.Text;
        string CIn=CheckIN.Text;
        string  COut=CheckOut.Text;
        string  AdultNo=Adult.Text;
        string  ChildNo=Child.Text;
        string InfantNo=Infant.Text;
        string RoomNos=RoomNo.Text;

        TestObject obj = new TestObject();

        obj.Stat=Statustxt.Text;
        obj.FirstName = txtfName.Text;
        obj.LastName = txtlName.Text;
        obj.Address=txtAddr.Text;
        obj.Cities=City.Text;
        obj.States= State.Text;
        obj.Countries =Country.Text;
        obj.PhoneNos= PhoneNo.Text;;
        obj.EmailId= EmailID.Text;
        obj.PinCode=Pincode.Text;
        obj.CIn=CheckIN.Text;
        obj.COut=CheckOut.Text;
        obj.AdultNo=Adult.Text;
        obj.ChildNo=Child.Text;
        obj.InfantNo=Infant.Text;
        obj.RoomNos=RoomNo.Text;

        string spName = "UPDATE";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);

        conn.Open();

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stat", obj.Stat);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.FirstName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.LastName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", obj.Address);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cities", obj.Cities);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@States", obj.States);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Countries", obj.Countries);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNos", obj.PhoneNos);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", obj.EmailId);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PinCode", obj.PinCode);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIn", obj.CIn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COut", obj.COut);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdultNo", obj.AdultNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildNo", obj.ChildNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InfantNo", obj.InfantNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNos", obj.RoomNos);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Customer Details updated in system");
    }
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE] 
    @Id int,
    @Stat nvarchar(100),
    @FirstName nvarchar(100),
    @LastName nvarchar(100),
    @Address nvarchar(100),
    @Cities nvarchar(100),
    @States nvarchar(100),
    @Countries nvarchar(100),
    @PhoneNos int,
    @EmailId nvarchar(100),
    @PinCode int,
    @CIn nvarchar(100),
    @COut nvarchar(100),
    @AdultNo int,
    @ChildNo int,
    @InfantNo int, 
    @RoomNos int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE [Hotel].[dbo].[Details] SET
[Status] = @Stat,
   [FirstName] = @FirstName,
  [LastName] = @LastName,
  [Address] = @Address,
  [City] = @Cities,
  [State] =@States ,
  [Country] = @Countries,
  [PhoneNo] = @PhoneNos,
  [EmailId] = @EmailId,
  [Pincode] = @PinCode,
  [CheckIn] = @CIn,
  [CheckOut] = @COut,
  [AdultNo] = @AdultNo,
  [ChildNo] = @ChildNo,
  [InfantNo] = @InfantNo,
  [RoomNo] = @RoomNos
WHERE ID = @Id

END
```

Comment: don't call a stored procedure 'UPDATE !!!! for obvious reasons....

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. as Mitch Wheat wrote in the comments, NEVER use keywords as procedures names.

b. as marc_s wrote in his comment - stop using .AddWithValue(). read the article he links to.

c. you never provide the @id parameter to the command , this is why you get the error.

d. this has nothing to do with winforms.

e. in the future, Please provide only the relevant code. if the problem is in the update button click, we don't need to see the entire form class, only the button click event handler.